# Help with aligning equations

Tags: equations, align, amsmath, cases

Can anyone, please, help me with a code to align the equations the same as the picture attached ?

I have tried to insert a big bracket to cover the two equations on the left side image but i do not know why my bracket cover just one equation.

Sincerely regards,
Sérgio

[image: equation with a huge bracket covering the two equation on the left side]

Comment: Could you include the code of your equations? Then it's easier to help you.

Comment: Did you want to simply *reproduce* the equations in the image? If so, then using the `cases` environment within an `equation` environment will give you the big brace on the left. If not, please be more specific on how you want to align things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a simple way to achieve this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amstext}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
\displaystyle
\nu(z_0)+\frac{g}{f}\frac{\partial\,\eta_s}{\partial\,x}
=\frac{g}{f}\frac{\partial\,\eta}{\partial\,x}\\[15pt]
\displaystyle\text{with }\nu(z_0) = 
\frac{1}{f\rho_0}\frac{\partial\,P_{z0}}{\partial\,x}
\end{cases}
\Rightarrow \eta = \eta_s+ \frac{P_{z0}}{\rho_0g}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Using `amsmath`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
If you want it center-aligned inside the braces, use \texttt{gathered}
\begin{equation}
    \left\{
        \begin{gathered}
            v(z_0) + \frac{g}{f} \frac{\partial\eta_s}{\partial x} = \frac{g}{f} \frac{\partial \eta}{\partial x} \\
            \text{with } v(z_0) = \frac{1}{f\rho_0} \frac{\partial P_{z0}}{\partial x} \text{ (junk to show alignment)} 
        \end{gathered}
        \right. \implies \eta = \eta_s + \frac{P_{z0}}{\rho_0 g}
    \end{equation}

If you want it either left-aligned, it is slightly simpler:
\begin{equation}
        \begin{cases}
            v(z_0) + \frac{g}{f} \frac{\partial\eta_s}{\partial x} = \frac{g}{f} \frac{\partial \eta}{\partial x} \\
            \text{with } v(z_0) = \frac{1}{f\rho_0} \frac{\partial P_{z0}}{\partial x} \text{ (junk to show alignment)}
        \end{cases}
        \implies \eta = \eta_s + \frac{P_{z0}}{\rho_0 g}
    \end{equation}

If for some reason you want it right aligned, you can use \texttt{aligned}

\begin{equation}
    \left\{
        \begin{aligned}
             v(z_0) + \frac{g}{f} \frac{\partial\eta_s}{\partial x} = \frac{g}{f} \frac{\partial \eta}{\partial x} \\
             \text{with } v(z_0) = \frac{1}{f\rho_0} \frac{\partial P_{z0}}{\partial x} \text{ (junk to show alignment)}
        \end{aligned}
        \right. \implies \eta = \eta_s + \frac{P_{z0}}{\rho_0 g}
    \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'd go with `cases` for the second example (and remove the third).

Comment: @egreg If the OP does want center or right alignment, I don't know how you can do it with cases. (The image the OP includes happened to have the two lines practically exactly the same length, so I don't know what the alignment needs are.)

Comment: @egreg edited. Too lazy to re-build the image file. (Also, I guess I am a bit silly in that I always find it uncomfortable to use `cases` when the lines are not really different "cases".)

Answer (score 3):

I would do it this way, using the `dcases` and `rcases`  environment from `mathtools`. Also, the `esdiff` package simplifies typing (partial) derivatives.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{fourier, erewhon}
\usepackage{esdiff}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \begin{rcases}\begin{dcases}
    ν(z₀)+\frac{g}{f}\diffp{\eta_s}{x}
    =\frac{g}{f}\diffp{η}{x}\\[0.5ex]
    \text{with }ν(z₀) =
    \frac{1}{f\rho₀}\diffp{P_{z0}}{x}
    \end{dcases}\end{rcases}
     ⇒ η= \eta_s+ \frac{P_{z0}}{\rho₀g}
    \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]